# How to properly convert controller and service from AngularJS to using ng-resource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I only started learning ng-resource recently. I'm wondering if I am on the right track when it comes to converting my regular AngularJS application to one which uses ng-resource.

This is my old `home.js` controller (without using ng-resource):

```
angular.module("HomeApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        BaseService.fetch.posts(function() {
            self.posts = BaseService.posts;
            self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
        });

        self.like = function(id, postType) {
            BaseService.like(id, postType, function() {
                self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

And this is my old `base.js` (BaseService):

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var self = this;
        self.posts = [];
        self.cerrorMessages = [];
        self.accessErrors = function(data) {
             self.cerrorMessages = [];
             for (prop in data) {
                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                     self.cerrorMessages.push(data[prop]);
                 }
             }
         };

        self.fetch = {
             posts: function(callback) {
                 $http.get('/posts/')
                 .then(function(response) {
                     self.posts = response.data;
                     callback();
                 }, function(response) {
                     self.accessErrors(response.data);
                     callback();
                 });
             }
         };

        self.like = function(id, postType, callback) {
            $http.post("/" + postType + "/" + id + "/like/")
            .then(function(response) {
                angular.forEach(self.posts, function(post, index, obj) {
                    if (post.id == id) {
                        post.usersVoted.push('voted');
                        post.voted=true;
                    };
                });
            }, function(response) {
                 self.accessErrors(response.data);
                 callback();
            });
        };

        return self;
    }]);
```

I was told that I can greatly benefit from using ng-resources since I have a RESTful backend. I tried converting the code above to start using ng-resource, and this is what I have now. This is my `resources.js`:

```
angular.module('PostsResources', ['ngResource'])

.factory('PostsFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/posts/:postId', { postId:'@id' });
});

.factory('PostLikeFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/posts/:postId/like', { postId:'@id' });
});
```

And this is my controller (`home.js`):

```
angular.module("HomePageApp", ["BaseApp", "PostsApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", "PostsResource", "PostLikeResource", function($http, $window, BaseService, PostsResource, PostLikeResource) {

var self = this;

function loadPosts() {
    self.posts = PostsFactory.query(function(data) {},
        function(error) {
          BaseService.accessErrors(error.data);
          self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
        }
    );
};

self.like = function likePost() {
    PostLikeFactory.save(function(data) {
        angular.forEach(self.posts, function(post, index, obj) {
            if (post.id == id) {
                post.usersVoted.push('voted');
                post.voted=true;
            };
        });
    }, function(error) {
        BaseService.accessErrors(error.data);
        self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
    }
)};
```

And this is my BaseService (`base.js`):

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var self = this;
        self.posts = [];
        self.cerrorMessages = [];
        self.accessErrors = function(data) {
             self.cerrorMessages = [];
             for (prop in data) {
                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                     self.cerrorMessages.push(data[prop]);
                 }
             }
         };
        return self;
    }]);
```

Am I on the right track of converting a regular AngularJS app to using ng-resource? To me it seems like the amount of code required looks the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Main point is: User = $resource('/user') -> User.get(), User.post, .... If you use only one method for each url - there is no much profit from ng-resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Mark that you probably don't have enough operations in your API to fully take advantage of $resource, so the benefits aren't as great. For what you have now though, if you're wanting to use $resource, I would set it up like this:

```
angular.module('PostsResources', ['ngResource'])
   .factory('Post', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/posts/:postId', { postId:'@id' }, {
         like: {
            url: '/posts/:postId/like',
            method: 'POST',
            params: { postId:'@id' }
         }
      })
   });
```

If you get to where you're using more than one action per endpoint, I would have a Post and PostLike resource, but in your case, that's not necessary.

In your controller, you'll be able to work with your posts like this:

```
self.posts = Post.query(null, BaseService.errorHandler(self));

self.like = function(post) {
   post.$like(function() {
      angular.forEach(self.posts, function(post, index, obj) {
            if (post.id == id) {
                post.usersVoted.push('voted');
                post.voted=true;
            };
        });
   }, BaseService.errorHandler(self));
};
```

The errorHandler method you could add to your BaseService to get rid of some duplication. It would look something like this:

```
self.errorHandler = function(viewModel) {
   return function(error) {
      BaseService.accessErrors(error.data);
      viewModel.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
   };
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally, I only use ng-resource when I have complete CRUD web applications.  Example would be a CRM kind of app, where you need to create customers, update customers, delete customers and show a list of customers.  It makes sense to use ng-resource as it "handles" the `get`, `post`, `put`, and `delete` HTTP methods for you.

However, in your example, it seems like the only actions you have is "Like" and "Getting a list of Posts".  If you are **ONLY** going to use one of the HTTP methods, for each resource type, then I'd suggest just sticking to your old way of using the `BaseService`.

Just my 2 cents on this matter.